# Camera base64 image cannot be converted to Bitmap

Tags: android

I have been having trouble converting the base64 String Image that is being sent to me by the backend.

So this is how the backend sends the data.

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     try {
         ImageIO.write(img, formatName, Base64.getEncoder().wrap(os));
         return os.toString(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());
     } catch (final IOException ioe) {
         throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
     }
```

And this is how we convert it.

```
final byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);

            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

The result is always null. Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

These are the back end codes.

```
        @Override
        public BufferedImage base64ToImage(String base64Image) throws IOException {

            byte[] imageBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Image);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));

            return img;
        }
        public static String imgToBase64String(final RenderedImage img, final String formatName) {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                ImageIO.write(img, formatName, Base64.getEncoder().wrap(os));
                return os.toString();
            } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
            }
        }
```

And this is our converting tool before sending the Base64 Image String to the back end.

```
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

        return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Comment: What is the length of `data` when decoding is done?

Comment: @EricB. 372255, TIA

Comment: In my case, when image size is greater than 1 MB it give an error or sometimes doing nothing. You can try this link: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/   --- Hope this help you.

Comment: I think `os.toString(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());` is the line that messes it up. Try changing it to `os.toString();`

Comment: @MahmudurRahman I have no control over the back end as I am not the one who develop it, it's also made of Java EE. As for Base64, I convert it to Base64 before sending it.

Comment: @EricB. Yeah, that's what I also thought of. I'll ask her if she could do that.

Comment: You can use this method:  public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

Comment: @MahmudurRahman I told you, I convert it to Base64 before I send it, I compress it to .PNG format. The problem I am having is that I can't convert the image that is being sent back to me.

Comment: 372255 bytes for an image. What is it? A .jpg? That will probably be to large to make a bitmap out of it. Just save these bytes to file to inspect with a normal photo viewer. Or let you send a much smaller .jpg.

Comment: @greenapps I formatted it to PNG before sending it. Teach me how to save these bytes to a file and inspect it.

Comment: You better google for save byte array to file. And you really want me to teach you how to view the pictures on your device? But start with a much smaller png. In size and especially in resolution.

Comment: @greenapps will probably save byte array to file.

Answer (score 0):

Check that ur base64 encoded string does not start with `data:image/jpg;base64,`. If it does then remove it. The Base64.decode won't be able to decode it in this case. u can remove it by using `encodedString.substring(encodedString.indexOf(",")  + 1);`. Let me know if this solves ur problem.

Comment: It doesn't. I am running on debug mode, I should've added that to the part of the question if it does.

Comment: can't post the whole string.

Comment: thatz ok. the point is if the string exists then decodeByteArray returning null means that it is unable to decode the string. The reason possibly being that it is not well-formatted.

Comment: These are the few lines.

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAkAAAAQACAIAAACGcHE3AACAAElEQVR42oy9iZdkV3Hu23/Ye2vddW2knmrIec6secqsrLlynrOGboGEJEsyIBBCAskMQoDFJEBGIGEjMxhsg21sjHm24dqMxjbXy6Zf7Ii948QesoSIddh58mRWVnX3+dUX8e2Ia5NOc9ptjdsNiFHrlBaTbmPcOYWn6KSKbhNi2GlAjAdtiFG/BUGLYa856DYg6AJ4Ib0WjvQqWJz12hDwtdSzvda415r02/AsLPidB+1T9f691nTQnQy602FvOuzCw7NB

Comment: is the original file size 1kb or less than that?

Comment: I'm not sure, after I take a picture using camera. I send it to the back end in Base64 format.

Comment: ur camera wont give u 1kb image. the above string is invalid, though i have not tested. y dont u post ur entire code.

Comment: That's the entire code, you mean the encoded string that is being sent back to me? I can't post it here as it is more than 500 characters.

Comment: then mail it at r.doleyz1993@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Vryin, I have checked the string. both urs and a well-formatted 1. The string is invalid. Show me ur code with which u got this string. U can mail me.

Comment: That is the string returned by the back end using the code I provided with the question. It's an image I suppose.

Comment: The above code is not enough to reproduce for testing... one shud post the question such that it can be reproduced and tested.

Comment: I can't provide the back end's code because I am not the developer of the back end. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
        ImageView driverImage = (ImageView) driverReportView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewDriverImage);
        try {
            byte [] encodeByte = Base64.decode(driverImageString.replace("\'/", "/"), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            if (bitmap != null)
                driverImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG,"Error to display driver info "+ex.toString());
        }
```

**Where**

`driverImageString` is your image string

Comment: No, just getting null at this line "Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);"

Comment: I think you have problem with image string. You can check your bytes from here http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: It converted the string to Image.